# "failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown" when serializing account info for Solana tutorial

Tags: typescript, rust, blockchain, solana

I get the above error when serializing account info for a Solana tutorial in Rust. Through brute force and print statements, I deduced that the error is occurring on serialization of the input_data object in the code below.

```
pub fn process_instruction(
   program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the GM program was loaded into
   accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say GM to
   input: &[u8], // String input data, contains the name to say GM to
) -> ProgramResult {

    msg!("GM program entrypoint");

    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
 
    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
 
    if account.owner != program_id {
        msg!("Greeted account does not have the correct program id");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }
 
    let mut input_data = GreetingAccount::try_from_slice(&input).unwrap();
 
    msg!("GM {}", input_data.name);
    input_data.counter += 1;

    msg!("Greeted {} time(s)!", input_data.counter);
 
    input_data.serialize(&mut &mut account.try_borrow_mut_data()?[..])?;
 
   Ok(())
}
```

See my definition of the GreetingAccount struct in the backend (Rust):

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
   pub name: String,
   pub counter: u32,
}
```

and in the front end (typescript):

```
 class GmAccount {
    name = "";
    counter = 0;
    constructor(fields: {name: string, counter: number} | undefined = undefined) {
      if (fields) {
        this.name = fields.name;
        this.counter = fields.counter;
      }
    }
    static schema = new Map([[GmAccount,
        {
            kind: 'struct',
            fields: [
                ['name', 'string'],
                ['counter', 'u32']]
        }]]);
 }
```

This started failing when I attempted to add the counter field, it worked just wine with only the name in the struct. I suspect is it something to do with letting the serializer know that the struct now also includes a number. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the solana cookbook serialization. Also, you can't use an account that was initialized for just a `string` and then add a new data structure. Try it with a brand new program owned account being initialized with the new data structure.